# iOS Swift appending value to array

Tags: ios, arrays, parse-platform, append, tableview

My Question is very simple,

I'm Learning iOS development and I'm stuck with tableviewcontroller

I can add Values to tableview with array, but when I try to append value from Parse, it's not working.

Here is the code:

```
var names: [String] = ["Name_one", "Name_two"]
let query: PFQuery! = PFUser.query()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    query.whereKey("objectId", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { objects, error in
        if (error == nil) {
            for user: PFUser in (objects as! [PFUser]) {


            self.names.append(user.username as! String)

            }
        } else {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
```

[Screen Shot Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu0Gg.png)

Comment: Update your question with relevant error details, so that we can help with debugging

Comment: there is no error, it's just that the value doesn't get appended to the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to reload your tableview after get data finished

Code:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { objects, error in
    if (error == nil) {
        for user: PFUser in (objects as! [PFUser]) {


        self.names.append(user.username as! String)

        }
        yourTableview.reloadData()
    } else {
        print("Error")
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I know, what's the name of my TableView?
sry I'm really stuck at basics

Comment: OOP@@ i don't know, this is your uitableview. if you use UItableviewController so it is self.tableview. If you add UITableview to UIViewController , it 's outlet of tableview in storyboard

Comment: so do I need to add

self.tableview.reloadData()

??

Comment: :D i 'm not sure because i don't know what 's your uitableview, but try   it

Comment: I think it's self.tableView.reloadData().

Comment: hah, finally it worked, with

self.tableView.reloadData()

thans @NguyenHoan and Rashmi